# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity error in logcat

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I want to locate location in map and my code was running correctly but suddenly I face these errors and after it my app is not running correctly. My java code is

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
        GoogleMap myMap;

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private static final double SEATTLE_LAT = 47.60621,
                SEATTLE_LNG = -122.33207,
                SYDNEY_LAT = -33.867487,
                SYDNEY_LNG = 151.20699,
                NEWYORK_LAT = 40.714353,
                NEWYORK_LNG = -74.005973;

        private static final float DEFAULTZOOM = 15;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (servicesOK()){
                setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

                if(initMap1()){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    gotoLocation(SEATTLE_LAT, SEATTLE_LNG,DEFAULTZOOM);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Map not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }           

            }
            else{

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
        }

        private boolean initMap() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public boolean servicesOK(){
            int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this); 

            if(isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
                return true;
            }
            else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)){
                Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
                dialog.show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to Google Play Services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return false;


        }
        private boolean initMap1() {
            if (myMap == null){
            SupportMapFragment mapFrag =
                    (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            myMap = mapFrag.getMap();
            }
        return (myMap != null);
        }
        private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng){
            LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            CameraUpdate update =  CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ll);
            myMap.moveCamera(update);
        }

        public void geoLocate(View v) throws IOException{
            hideSoftKeyboard(v);

            EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String location = myEditText.getText().toString();



            Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
            List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
            Address add = list.get(0);
            String locality = add.getLocality();
            Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            double lat = add.getLatitude();
            double lng = add.getLongitude();

            gotoLocation(lat, lng, DEFAULTZOOM);
        }

        private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng, float zoom) {
            LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            CameraUpdate update =  CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
            myMap.moveCamera(update);


        }

        private void hideSoftKeyboard(View v) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

        } 

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

and logcat is

```
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097): Process: com.nabia.Try, PID: 4097
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4240)
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5184)
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20910)
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4235)
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     ... 10 more
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Timed out waiting for response from server
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:178)
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at com.nabia.Try.MainActivity.geoLocate(MainActivity.java:114)
09-17 23:39:56.336: E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     ... 13 more
```

anybody please tell me what should I do to resolve these errors.

Comment: Given that the exception was "Caused by: java.io.IOException: Timed out waiting for response from server", perhaps the server is down?

Comment: oh thank u that was my mistake server was not available. thank u :)